# google plus api 403

Tags: google-plus, http-status-code-403

For some reason I’m not getting the results that I expected using the HTTP POST explorer. I’m getting 403 Forbidden for all userIds that I try. 
I used this article to be sure I'm using the correct userId (I even used the userID from the article to see if it was just the ones I tested).

This is where I'm testing: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plusDomains/v1/plusDomains.activities.list

Could there be something wrong with the API?

Here's the full response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide a link to the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Plus Domain API, you need to make sure the user you're authenticating as is part of the domain you're making queries for. See https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/ for more details.